# «Оттого» или «от того»? — в конкретном предложении

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

*Одесса, где все до последней травинки малой настояно юмором, самоиронией. Где шутят все и над всеми. Где Черное море смягчает нравы, **оттого** народ получается добродушный и незлобивый. Где ты, старая добрая Одесса?..*
[И. Невинная. Швондер на все времена.](https://www.mke.ee/mnenie/pamyati-romana-kartseva-malenkij-chelovek-iz-odessy) МК-Эстония, 10.10.2018

Обспорились на работе, но так и не смогли понять — по смыслу слитно или раздельно.
Как правильно? Подскажите, помогите разрешить наш спор.

Answer (score 3):

> [ОТТОГО](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20), местоим. нареч. Поэтому, по этой причине. Рассеянный ты, о. все твои ошибки. Устал, о. сердит. <Оттого и, в зн. союза. Потому и. Усерден, оттого и отличник. Оттого что, в зн. союза. Потому что. Не пришёл на свидание, оттого что не смог. А (и) оттого, в зн. союза. А (и) потому. Собран и оттого много успевает.
>
> оттого, нареч. (оттого мне и весело), но местоим. от того (от того, что он сказал, многое зависит)

Конечно же здесь наречие (оттого = поэтому, по этой причине). Пишется слитно.

Comment: Дело в том, что некоторые считают, что можно задать вопрос _от чего?_ "Народ получается добродушный и незлобивый" — от чего? — от юмора, от самоиронии, от Черного моря...

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Так ведь "отчего?" здесь по тем же причинам пишется вместе. Поскольку можно заменить вопросом "почему?".

Comment: А как вам такое сравнение: 1) Черное море смягчает нравы, оттого (и) народ получается добродушный и незлобивый. 2) Черное море смягчает нравы, от этого  (от чего?) и  народ получается добродушный и незлобивый.  Почему разное написание?

Comment: Да-да, именно такими и были рассуждения-сравнения.

Comment: @Ксения Вы вносите путаницу своими вопросами без ответов. Можно подумать, что в данном предложении допустимо писать раздельно (от того), но это не так.

Comment: Я не вношу путаницу, а стараюсь понять правило. А правило мне представляется ФОРМАЛЬНЫМ. Мы пишем слитно наречие оттого и союз оттого что (предлог здесь переходит в приставку), но пишем раздельно местоимение от того  в СПП.  Однако, это принятая  УСЛОВНОСТЬ, что видно из примера "от этого". Вся разница в том, что у нас нет слова "отэтого", хотя есть слова "поэтому, оттого". Получается, что в этой теме не задаются вопросы, а просто с помощью формы написания различаются, с одно стороны, союзы и наречия, а с другой, местоименные указательные слова.

Comment: В своем ответе я уже указывала на союз "из-за того что",  который пишется раздельно по формальным соображениям, хотя по значению он равен союзу "оттого что"

Answer (score 3):

**Где Черное море смягчает нравы, оттого народ получается добродушный и незлобивый.**

Выбор формы написания оттого/от того определяется **строго формально**. **Раздельная форма** *от того* используется только  в СПП с местоименной связью, когда в состав придаточного входит союзное слово, а не союз. Только тогда можно задать падежный вопрос (от чего?).

Сравним:

1) Характер народа зависит (от чего?) от того, что его окружает/какая природа его окружает (от того — местоимение, падежное управление; что/какая — союзные слова, члены предложения).

2)  Народ получается добродушный и незлобивый *оттого, что* его окружает красивая природа, мягкий климат (*оттого, что* — составной союз, местоимение *что* не является членом предложения).

В других случаях (при отсутствии падежного управления) *оттого* пишется **только слитно** (падежные вопросы не задаются, возможна замена синонимом *поэтому*). Наречие *оттого* используется в БСП. Есть еще присоединительный союз в СПП: *оттого и*.

Примечание. Реже используются союз *из-за того что*.  Здесь раздельное написание сложного предлога *из-за*, который не может соединиться с местоимением.

Варианты предложения:

БСП с наречием: Где Черное море смягчает нравы, *оттого* народ получается добродушный и незлобивый.

СПП с присоединительным союзом: Где Черное море смягчает нравы, *оттого и*   народ получается добродушный и незлобивый.