# Почему используется «от того» вместо «оттого»?

Tags: грамматика, предлоги, союзы

Михаил Булгаков, «Мастер и Маргарита», глава 25:

> Слуга, перед грозою накрывавший для прокуратора стол, почему-то растерялся под его взглядом, взволновался **от того**, что чем-то не угодил, и прокуратор, рассердившись на него, разбил кувшин о мозаичный пол...

Предполагаю, что правильнее будет использовать «оттого», но авторитет Булгакова меня выигрывает. Всё-таки нужно использовать «от того» или это ошибка Булгакова/Изданий/Редакторов и т. д.?

Comment: Он точно не угодил прокуратору и знал об этом наверняка? Если нет, то необходимо использовать: *что мог чем-то не угодить*. Иначе это как логическая ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю, что это ошибка. Если глагол сочетается с предлогом ‟от”, как, например, глагол ‟умереть” (умереть от старости, умереть от рака), то допустимы оба варианта написания:
1 От умер от того(предлог + местоимение), что не продезинфицировал рану.
2 Он умер оттого(только союз), что не продезинфицировал рану.
Если же глагол не сочетается с предлогом ‟от”, как глагол ‟взволновался”, то допустим только один вариант:
Он взволновался оттого, что не тренировался.

Нельзя ведь сказать: «Я волновался от последних событий», ‟Я рассмеялся от шутки”, ‟Он удивился от сюрприза”. Эти глаголы не сочетаются с предлогом ‟от”. Так почему же можно писать: ‟рассмеялся от того”, ‟волновался от того”, ‟удивился от того”? Это грамматическая ошибка с предлогом и падежом.

Comment: Здесь союз, а не предлог. И надо выбрать вид союза, изъяснительный или причинный (они пишутся по-разному).

Answer (score 1):

Нашел два источника, в которых ***оттого*** написано слитно. Думаю, что правильно именно так.

[**Михаил Булгаков. Жизнь и творчество**](http://m-bulgakov.ru/sochineniya/master-i-margarita-okonchatelnaya-redakciya/p25)
[**Русская историческая библиотека**](http://rushist.com/index.php/rus-literature/6977-bulgakov-master-i-margarita-chast-2-chitat-onlajn-po-glavam#c25)

Есть составной союз [***оттого(,) что***](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_518), и есть сочетание предлога ***от*** с местоимением ***того***, после которых идет местоименное существительное [***ЧТО***](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE) («Указывает на предмет, явление, ситуацию, о которых идёт речь»).

*Было хорошо оттого, что он услышал это.

Было хорошо от того, чтó он услышал.*

> [**Вопрос № 281500**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)
>
> Как разграничить оттого что и от того что? Чем руководствоваться при написании?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Союз *оттого что* можно заменить синонимичным союзом *потому что*. Запятая может ставиться перед союзом или между его частями. Ср.: *я счастлива оттого, что он сказал мне эти слова / я счастлива, оттого что он сказал мне эти слова (= я счастлива потому, что он сказал мне эти слова / я счастлива, потому что он сказал мне эти слова) – многое зависит от того, чтó он скажет* (здесь сочетание предлога с местоимением *от того*, заменить союзом *потому что* невозможно, запятая может быть поставлена только перед *что*, на *что* падает ударение).

Comment: Нельзя ведь сказать: «Я волновался от последних событий», ‟Я рассмеялся от шутки”, ‟Он удивился от сюрприза”. Эти слова не сочетаются с предлогом ‟от”. Так почему же можно говорить: ‟рассмеялся от того”, ‟волновался от того”, ‟удивился от того”? Это грубая грамматическая ошибка с предлогом и падежом.

Comment: Хорошо, удалил эти предложения. Хотя я бы откорректировал словарь управления :)  По мне так *волноваться от чего-то* нормально звучит.

Comment: Не звучит прямо ужасно, да, но все равно, для носителя, слегка режет слух. Если откорректировать словарь, если люди массово начнут так говорить, то тогда это будет отлично звучать, потому это звучание и есть массовое использование предлога определенным образом.

Comment: *Они долго оставались в кухне, и я сильно волновался от неизвестности* (Фазиль Искандер). *Он волновался от жадности, рассчитывая сорвать состояние* (А. С. Грин).

Comment: По поводу использования предлогов, то это очень тонкие материи, и можно что угодно найти среди всей литературы, даже среди классиков.

Comment: Просто такая вещь, как грамматические ошибки, это не просто: ты совершаешь ошибку — никто не понимает смысл. Грамматические ошибки, как, например, неправильно использование предлогов, может вызывать: непонимание смысла, затруднительное понимание смысла, сильно режущее слух восприятие, слабо режущее слух восприятие, легко режущее слух восприятие и т.д. Эти примеры и попадают в категорию слабо режущих восприятие.

Answer (score 1):

Второй ответ

*Слуга, перед грозою накрывавший для прокуратора стол, почему-то растерялся под его взглядом, взволновался **ОТ ТОГО, ЧТО** чем-то не угодил, и прокуратор, рассердившись на него, разбил кувшин о мозаичный пол...*

Так написано **в издании 1988 года**, а первая книга в СССР вышла в 1973 году. Наверное, литературоведы разбираются в редакциях романа и знают,  какой текст следует считать каноническим. Это специалисты должны сказать: **Считаю, что правильно именно так.**  Вы себя относите к ним, **чтобы говорить об этом с такой уверенностью?**

Слишком большая ответственность — правка классического текста. Пара изданий и мнение Грамоты.ру о **единственно правильном понимании** русской грамматики для меня не авторитет. Я неплохо знаю, как трактуются наши правила, как часто они меняются.

Чтобы меньше было хлопот, а население становилось все более грамотным, есть проверенный метод — **упрощение и сведение к минимуму тонких семантических** оттенков, которые уже недоступны многим пользователям.

**Поэтому я за текст Булгакова**, за его понимание смысла сказанного, и никто не убедит меня в том, что правы другие. Ни логикой, ни правилами, которые **не академики подгоняли под один стандарт**, а вполне возможно, что абсолютно равнодушные к русской литературе люди. Я не верю ни им, ни их правилам.

А вы голосуйте! Кто там за слитное написание? Все единогласно "за"!  Единодушие и единомыслие (вернее, одномыслие) — это очень здорово!  Я за вас рада. И нет слов, чтобы сказать, как **разочарована** этим вашим единодушным мнением. Будто лишилась разом многих хороших друзей.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ОТ 02.10.2021**

Нет у меня особого настроения продолжать эту тему, поэтому добавлю совсем немного.

1. Союзы ПОТОМУ ЧТО и ОТТОГО ЧТО считаются синонимами.  **Но точно ли они полные синонимы?** Предлог ПО указывает общую направленность на ситуацию, а предлог ОТ ясно называет предмет в качестве причины.
   При этом построены союзы одинаково – во второй части там  изъяснительный союз, а не союзное слово.  Поэтому они позволяют описывать ситуацию или **в общих чертах**, или с более конкретным указанием **на предмет беспокойства**.
2. И вот у Булгакова обозначен именно предмет – **нечто неизвестное,** какой-то проступок, который слуга сам себе вообразил.
3. Союз ОТ ТОГО ЧТО  имеет право на существование, он построен **по точной грамматике:** указательная местоименная часть + изъяснительный союз.
4. **И делаем выводы**

Здесь замена  союзом  ПОТОМУ ЧТО  нежелательна.
Здесь указан конкретный предмет –  «чем-то». Поэтому можно использовать союз ОТ ТОГО ЧТО.

Это грамматически правильный союз, никто его не отменял.

В Нацорпусе много примеров, где используется ОТ ТОГО ЧТО, и в этих примерах  ЧТО – изъяснительный союз (не союзная часть!).  Обычные пользователи понимают разницу в употреблении  различных причинных  союзов и противятся стремлению все нивелировать и обезличить.

А что тогда говорить о великом писателе!

Comment: Sharon, зря вы так насчет друзей... И уж очень вы преувеличиваете: где "единодушное мнение" и "все единогласно "за"? А слово "считаю" (здесь вы правы) поменяю на "думаю" – всё-таки помягче, думаю :).

Comment: Заглянул сегодня 2 раза в вашу Школу (это добавило читателей?). Здорово, что теперь можно обращаться туда! Успехов, новых открытий и, конечно, творческих свершений!

Comment: Спасибо, я пока еще не очень довольна материалом (это как бы черновой вариант), но постараюсь довести его до совершенства. Если есть желание, помогайте  советами. Пусть это будет нашим общим делом.

Comment: В окончательной редакции написано всё-таки слитно. В рукописях до неё вообще нет "взволновался оттого, что".

Answer (score 1):

**Евгений:**

> Предполагаю, что правильнее будет использовать «оттого»…

**Вы правы.** См.:

> Выбор формы написания *оттого/от того* определяется **строго
> формально. Раздельная форма** *от того* используется только в СПП с
> местоименной связью, **когда в состав придаточного входит союзное
> слово, а не союз.** (Sharon)
>
> [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445175/Оттого-или-от-того-в-конкретном-предложении/445179#445179](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445175/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8/445179#445179)

Answer (score 1):

**UPD**. Предлагаю всем посмотреть бумажные издания в своей библиотеке и поделиться в комментариях (я потом подытожу сумму этих комментариев здесь). У меня в простеньком "Избранном" ("Просвещение", 1991) "от того" раздельно. А до добротного 5-томника я сейчас не могу дотянуться, надеюсь, у кого-то такой тоже есть.

Выше были ссылки на электронные издания со слитным написанием "оттого что". Я посчитал эти ссылки недостойными какого-либо внимания (по очевидным причинам) и решил найти что-то более авторитетное.

Нашёл подарочное издание со следующей аннотацией:

> В новом, юбилейном издании бессмертный роман представлен в его
> последней прижизненной авторской редакции (рукописи хранятся в
> рукописном отделе Государственной библиотеки СССР имени В. И. Ленина),
> а также с исправлениями и дополнениями, сделанными под диктовку
> писателя его женой, Еленой Сергеевной Булгаковой.

В этом издании написано раздельно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И чтобы ещё позабавить некоторых здешних ценителей русского языка, снисходительно обсуждающих корявость булгаковского стиля, приведу другую цитату из романа (кому-то будет приятно почувствовать себя ещё выше на этом фоне):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Grizzly, поделитесь, пожалуйста, своим опытом (говорю серьезно, мне правда интересно), по каким критериям Вы определяете достойность/недостойность источников. И можете дать ссылку на это подарочное издание? Или это скриншоты с бумажного? А то по аннотации предлагаются только сайты, где можно купить книгу.

Comment: Grizzly, в этом подарочном издании и _чорт_ ведь, наверное, написан с «о»?

Comment: @slava1947 Нет, во всех случаях через "е". До 1956 г. обычно допускались оба варианта (всё это нужно писать с длинными оговорками, но не об этом сейчас; google-сервисы говорят, что в книгах 20-30-х годов "черт" встречалось в 4 раза чаще). Я не знаю, как писал сам Булгаков и вполне могу допустить, что орфографию правили под современную. Но я не думаю, что что-то правили в другую сторону.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Есть несколько критериев, но я приведу основной: должен быть указан редактор издания. Для электронного издания должен быть указан редактор именно этого электронного текста, а не оригинала, с которого пиратскими методами малограмотные студенты делали распознавание. Я работал несколько лет в типографии Академии Наук и имею некоторый опыт в этих вопросах. К сожалению, опыт сложно передавать, поэтому я Вас тоже понимаю.

Comment: _Grizzly: Нет, во всех случаях через "е"._ === Ну, значит, это не совсем «прижизненная авторская редакция».

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец [Вот ссылка](https://libgen.is/fiction/?q=Мастер+и+маргарита). Пройдите оттуда по 1, 2, 3. Надеюсь, получится разобраться.

Comment: @slava1947 Ок, не буду спорить. Сам источник выглядит немного сомнительно, но всё же лучше распознанного FineReader'ом текста с автоматической коррекцией ошибок (с чего бы это распознавание не делалось).

Comment: Grizzly  Не получается разобраться. В 1 только аннотация, в 2 название, в 3 попасть совсем не удается.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Зайдите, например, в 2 и в самом верху нажмите "Get".

Comment: Да, спасибо, загрузилась книга.

Answer (score 0):

В данной книге собраны все доступные авторские редакции романа, и там написано слитно:
https://x0.at/bESf.pdf

Что интересно, там даже есть многоточия, где Булгаков планировал потом дописать.

Comment: Хороший источник. Значит, в "полной рукописной версии" этого "оттого" вообще не было, а было потом добавлено профессиональными текстологами в так называемую "окончательную редакцию". И затем, вероятно, правилось редакторами всех изданий по их усмотрению.

Comment: Кстати, здесь "черт" всегда через "е". Следовательно, это тоже не авторская орфография, а чья-то редактура?

Comment: Окончательная редакция — его жены. Типа она писала под его диктовку (указано на стр. 999), а как было на самом деле — нельзя знать наверняка. *Кстати, здесь "черт" всегда через "е"* — там же есть самые ранние рукописи, как там? И кто вообще сказал, что должно быть через О?

Comment: _**oleedd**: И кто вообще сказал, что должно быть через О?_ === Наверное, я. И имел на то основания. Написание «чорт» встретил в цитате из «М. и М.» в «Известиях Академии наук СССР» за 1980 год. Такое же написание имело место у Булгакова и в «Дьяволиаде» (1925 г.) (фото могу привести). Такое же написание фиксировалось и словарями в период написания Булгаковым «М. и М.»…